# how to integrate a progress bar for an AsyncTask thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am developing an app which takes data from user and posts it to a webservice. The network operation happens in an AsyncTask thread, sometimes it takes around 3 sec for the webservice to get, process and send a reply. I want to have a progress bar showing the progress of the activity. I searched a little and found a few guides but some of them were about video processing and such, I am unable to understand how to integrate it for my needs.

I am posting my AsyncTask thread code, please help me integrate the progress bar.

```
 private class DownloadOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        String uname = "";
        String email = "";
        String password = "";
        String confirmpass = "";
        String phone = "";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Get user defined values
            uname = username.getText().toString();
            email = mail.getText().toString();
            password = pass.getText().toString();
            confirmpass = cpass.getText().toString();
            phone = phn.getText().toString();

            //Progress Bar should go here?

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String response = "";
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://rgbpallete.in/led/api/signup");
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", uname));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", password));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", phone));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                return response;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String jsonStr) {
            super.onPostExecute(jsonStr);
            Log.d("tag", "Result:\n" + jsonStr);
            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    String message = jsonObj.getString("message");
                    boolean error = jsonObj.getBoolean("error");

                    error(error,message);

                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the .xml code for the progress bar in the layout `signup.xml`

```
<ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/comfirmpass"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:indeterminate="false" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Indeterminate Progress**:......

For an indeterminate progress bar, it's enough to

1. show it in the `onPreExecute` method, and
2. hide it in the `onPostExecute` method of your `AsyncTask` extension.

**2. Determinate progress**:

In order to bind a determinate progress bar to your background process, you need to call [`publishProgress`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress...%29) from the `doInBackground` method. This in turn will notify the UI thread by the [`onProgressUpdate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29), so if you override that one too, you'll be able to display the proper progress.

To do so, you'll also need to switch from the HttpClient way to a UrlConnection way, and process its output 'manually'.